# In 32-bit mode without paging, how to calculate the physical address?

Tags: assembly, x86, memory-address, memory-segmentation

I am brand new to assembly and was given the following task:

> If the processor is in protected 32-bit mode without paging, and for the segment connected to the DS selector states in the descriptor table that it starts from 00036D95h, and the EBX register has the value 000034A7h, from which physical locations will the value be moved to AL after instruction MOV AL, [EBX + 0016h]?

I tried looking on the web for any similar example, and couldn't find anything? Does anyone know some similar examples, or any formula to calculate the physical location?

EDIT:
Could you just sum up these three numbers to get the physical address?

Comment: From 00036D95h + 000034A7h + 0016h.

Comment: Yup, linear address is always segment_base + effective address aka offset.

Comment: Note that `00036D95h` is a terrible value to have for the DS selector base, since it misaligns everything. From the Intel documentation: "Segment base addresses should be aligned to 16-byte boundaries."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could you just sum up these three numbers to get the physical address?

Yeah, that's exactly how it works.

> Does anyone know some similar examples, or any formula to calculate the physical location?

In general, as [@Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes) and [@tkausl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1080064/tkausl) suggest above, the formula is `SEGMENT_BASE + OFFSET`. The `SEGMENT_BASE` is just given by the segment descriptor, while the `OFFSET` depends on the actual instruction. For MOV instructions (see [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34058101/3889449)) you can have:

```
MOV REG, [base_reg + index_reg*scale + displacement]
```

So the full formula becomes `SEGMENT_BASE + base_reg + index_reg*scale + displacement`. In your specific case you only have `base_reg` and `displacement`.

---

For reference, from the [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manuals](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/intel-sdm.html) vol 3A section 3.1 you can read:

> Each segment has a segment descriptor, which specifies the size of the segment, the access rights and privilege level for the segment, the segment type, and the location of the first byte of the segment in the linear address space (called the base address of the segment). The offset part of the logical address is added to the base address for the segment to locate a byte within the segment. **The base address plus the offset thus forms a linear address in the processor’s linear address space.**
>
> **If paging is not used, the linear address space of the processor is mapped directly into the physical address space** of the processor. The physical address space is defined as the range of addresses that the processor can generate on its address bus.

The following figure should give you an idea of how paging and segmentation can work together:

[image: fig-3-1]

Now since you don't have paging, if you remove the "Paging" part on the right, all you are left with is the "Segmentation" part, and you are in the following situation (notice the *"or Physical Memory"* on the right):

[image: fig-3-4]

Note that the above figure is just indicative, you don't necessarily need to have each segment register point to a different segment descriptor, but you can.